# Why hasn't the caulk cured in my shower?

Tags: shower, tile, floor, caulk

I have a lady I clean for ask me to remove the old caulking and redo it. So I did I used the normal home depot brand for years like I’ve always gotten. And the client said it never cured. So when I come over the next time there were spots in the “clear caulking” that were still white.. so we decide to go ahead and remove it and use a different brand, check the dates, Then I even ask some of the Home Depot employees which one to try this time.. and they show me and tell me how to use it.. I go ok . I get a message from my client, and she says she hasn’t used the shower since I reapplied it over the weekend and it is now a Monday.. confused on why this keeps happening.

Comment: Grout should not be used where the surfaces change direction, for example from a wall to a floor. This area will flex and need caulking instead. I like polyseamseal for waterproofing. Get the mold resistant type.

Comment: Please revise to tell us the _type_ of caulking. Brand is less important. (I didn't know Home Depot _had_ a brand.)

Comment: Willing to bet that it wasn’t one of the 100% silicone ones… please name the specific one. Bonus points for the date code.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, most clear caulks come out white and can take a few days or more to turn clear. That length of time can increase if the bead is a large or a deep one. It can also be caused by moisture being in the wall. If any water seeped into the wall while the old caulk was still there, the wall insides has to be totally dry before caulking. I'm curious as to why you're caulking a grout line instead of using a grout.